# How do I get the download url from firebase database and load it in my tableview imageview in a different viewcontroller?

Tags: swift

I have successfully referenced my download URL from firebase storage to firebase database. I am creating an events feed where I pull data from my "Church Events" node from auto id's (eventdate, eventloacation, ImagesUrl, event title). I want to load each post in a table view with the related information under the autoid. I am able to load everything but the Image which I need to retrieve from the URL in the ImageUrl field. Currently i have static images loading from an array. Is it possible to get help on this I am fairly new to swift and would greatly appreciate the help?

```swift
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class EventsViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var eventsRef: DatabaseReference?
    var eventsDatabaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?


    var eventsTitles = [String]()
    var eventTimestamps = [String]()
    var eventsLocations = [String]()
    var eventsImages = [UIImage]()


    @IBOutlet weak var addEventsButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageView: UIPageControl!


    var imgArr = [  UIImage(named:"1"),
                    UIImage(named:"2"),
                    UIImage(named:"3"),
                    UIImage(named:"4"),
                    UIImage(named:"5"),
                    UIImage(named:"6"),
                    UIImage(named:"7"),
                    UIImage(named:"8"),
                    UIImage(named:"9"),
                    UIImage(named:"10") ]

    var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadImages()


        eventsRef = Database.database().reference()

        tableView.reloadData()

  tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    eventsDatabaseHandle = eventsRef?.child("Church Events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in

         let eventPost = snaphot.value as! [String: Any]


      self.eventTimestamps.append(eventPost["eventdate"] as! String)


        self.eventsTitles.append(eventPost["eventtitle"] as! String)

self.eventsLocations.append(eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String)


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

//**************************************************************************


        if (Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName != "Neil Leon")  {
            self.addEventsButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            self.addEventsButton.isEnabled = false

        }
        else{

            self.addEventsButton.isEnabled = true
        }

}

    func loadImages(){
        eventsImages = imgArr as! [UIImage]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventsTitles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "events") as! EventsTableViewCell

        let image = eventsImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.flyerImages.image = image

        cell.eventTitle.text! = eventsTitles[indexPath.row]

        cell.eventDate.text! =  eventTimestamps[indexPath.row]

        cell.eventLocation.text! = eventsLocations[indexPath.row]


        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)


        return cell
    }

}
```

[image], [image]

Comment: First thing I am noticing, instead of having separate arrays for `eventsTitles`, `eventTimestamps`, `eventsLocations`, and `eventsImages`, you should probably make a custom object called `Event` with `title`, `timeStamp`, `location`, and `image` as properties of that type. Then you could have `var churchEvents = [Event]()` serve as a single data source for your table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is make a request to the url `String` stored on the database, take the returned `Data`, and turn this `Data` into a `UIImage`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {

    ...

    self.eventsLocations.append(eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: eventPost["ImageuUrl"] as! String)!) {(data, response, error) in

        if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
            self.eventsImages.append(image)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    ...
}
```

This should work for you, but I would **highly** recommend creating a custom `Event` class and have a single array of `Event` objects as your table view's data source. If you want to ask another question outlining how to do so, I could explain it for your specific case, otherwise, take a look here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: Hello David, this is awesome, thank you. I can definitely get the images loaded now. However, everytime i post an event the previous post shows up not the current one. Do you know why thats happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough context. This may warrant a new question.

Comment: Hi David, I added the bit of code you recommended and I first it seemed like it was working but now, no data is populating in my table view. I can see it being uploaded to my database but it's not loaded onto my table view.

Comment: Hi David, could you help me in creating the custom event?

Comment: I could, though it probably warrants creation of a new question. I'll be checking the swift tag this morning and if I see one, I'll go ahead and answer for you. Its just a bit off topic for this current question.